# jQuery UI Tabs does not load content correctly until window resize

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, tabs

I'm having some issues using jQuery UI Tabs in my Wordpress install. For some reason the content inside the tabs does not load correctly until the user resizes the window.

I'm not sure how to debug this, there's no errors on the page either.

[Link to the dev site](http://consept.screenpartner.no/property/haakon-viis-gt-25/)

**Before resize:**
[image: Table and image gallery does not load correctly until user resizes window]

**After resize:**
[image]

The problem is in the third tab, here's what's in it:

```
<div id="tabs-3">
    <article class="hentry">
        <section class="entry-content cf">
            <div class="blueprint-images">
                <?php

                $blueprint_slider = get_field('blueprints_images');
                if ($blueprint_slider == '') {
                    ?>
                    <div class="info">
                        <h3>Plantegninger – 2 flotte boliger på endetomt for salg</h3>
                        <p>Ta kontakt for tegninger og mer informasjon. Husene er ca. 200 kvm BRA.</p>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                } else {
                    echo do_shortcode( "[envira-gallery id=". $blueprint_slider->ID ."]" );
                    echo do_shortcode( "[envira-gallery slug=". $blueprint_slider->post_name ."]" );
                }

                ?>
            </div>

            <div class="blueprint-tables">
                <?php
                $tablepress_id = get_field('blueprints_sales_table');
                tablepress_print_table( array( 'id' => ".'$tablepress_id'.", 'use_datatables' => true, 'print_name' => false ) );
                ?>
            </div>
        </section>
    </article>
</div>
```

Comment: can you show the code how you are filling that tab (Tegninger)?

Comment: I added the code to the question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tab that contains the `Envira` images is not initially visible and has no dimensions at the time when Envira figures out the parent width. When you view the tab and then resize the browser, your `enviraSetWidths()` routine corrects this. However, note that if you resize the browser before visiting the third tab, and then visit the tab, the images are still small because the parent container (tab) had `width:0` before it was opened.

To fix this, bind to the `tabsactivate` event and trigger the `resize` handler:

```
$( "#tabs" ).on( "tabsactivate", function( event, ui ) 
{
  $(window).triggerHandler("resize");
} );
```

```js
$("#tabs").tabs();
var tabWidths = [];
$("div", "#tabs").each(function() {
  tabWidths.push({
    id: this.id,
    width: Math.round($(this).width())
  });
});

alert("Initial tab widths:\n" + JSON.stringify(tabWidths).replace(/,/g,',\n'));

$("#tabs").on("tabsactivate", function()
              {
  alert("Id: " + this.id + " -- width: " + Math.round($(this).width()));
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-3">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Alright, I added this, but I'm getting a ReferenceError: Can't find variable: envira_container_1114.

Comment: Make sure you add it in same scope as that. I think you can put the code right next to where you initially call `enviraSetWidths`

Comment: I'd rather not edit the Wordpress plugin. It might matter if that script is called before the initial plugin script is called?

Comment: What matters is that the images script is called before the parent tab `div` is visible. Try my updated solution.

Comment: `$(window).triggerHandler("resize"); ` worked perfectly! :) Thanks so much @nothingisnecessary