# jQuery image conflict with resizing browser window

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

Okay, this one has me confused as hell (I've spent hours trying to figure it out) so I am hoping perhaps a fresh set of eyes might be able to spot the culprit easier than I can.

The page in question is here: http://centerpointesigns.com/dev/portfolio/

Go to that page on a desktop and open one of the jQuery UI accordions. You should see some VERY tiny little images (gallery images).

Now, shrink your browser window down as tiny as possible, open an accordion and then slowly drag your browser window back to full size again. You should now see the same gallery images stretch with the page and rearrange accordingly until they get to the max page width.

This is how they should start out when you first visit the page, but for whatever reason or another they start out super tiny.

The accordions being used are jQuery UI accordions with no custom code other than the styling. The odd thing is that if I remove those gallery images from the jQuery accordion and put it elsewhere on the page (outside of the accordion container) then they work 100# fine, just as they should.

So, this appears to be some sort of jQuery conflict, I'm just completely lost as to what the issue might actually be.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is answered on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32221248/jquery-ui-tabs-does-not-load-content-correctly-until-window-resize) with the code modification to

```
$('#accordion').on('accordionactivate', function() {
  $(window).triggerHandler("resize");
});
```

Add that to `/dev/wp-content/themes/cps/js/functions.js` and you'll be good to go.

Comment: Wow, I wasn't expecting anyone would have an answer at all, but sure enough that solved it! Thanks a million